# Encoding for html in Open Graph Facebook attributes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have product titles such as

> Cheap Samsung 22" Television

which I need to include in an `og:title` tag as such:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Cheap Samsung 22&amp;quot; Television"/>
```

However when Facebook tries to render it within a rich snippet, it doesn't render the quotation and displays it as is:

> Cheap Samsung 22&quot; Television

I don't understand why it doesn't render it properly so it reads as intended? If I don't encode my string and just place it in there like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Cheap Samsung 22" Television"/>
```

Then Facebook thinks the quote at the end of the 22 which means inches is the end of the content attribute and hence the string gets chopped off like this:

> Cheap Samsung 22"

How do I tackle this? I am using ColdFusion's `EncodeForHTMLAttribute(mystring)` function to accomplish the HTML encoding on the content attribute.

UPDATE: The string was being double-encoded by ColdFusion. First on the way in to the database, and then once again when outputting on the page. I used `Canonicalize` after performing an Anti-Samy on the way in so the string didn't contain any encoding in the DB table. Problem solved.

Comment: Why are you encoding the ampersand in the first example? Have you tried `<meta property="og:title" content="Cheap Samsung 22&quot; Television"/>` ? Alternatively, have you tried using single quotes to wrap the `content` value like so, `<meta property="og:title" content='Cheap Samsung 22" Television'/>` ?

Comment: @ScottStroz The ampersand seems to be added by ColdFusion, its not my doing. I have tried single quotes but the problem will occur if anyone includes a single quote in their product title e.g. `World's best car`

Comment: Show us the actual CF code that is causing the issue as it becomes a much different question knowing that CF is part of the process to output the string. If CF is encoding the ampersand, sounds like maybe the string is already encoded and you are encoding it again..maybe?

Comment: @ScottStroz Ahh crap, you were right. When the ProductTitle is first being input into the DB, I did an anti-samy on it like this `GetSafeHTML(#FORM.ProductTitle#)` which has gone and escaped the quotation characters already. So its ending up getting double encoded. I didn't realise the anti-samy encodes characters? I thought it just stripped out illegal HTML characters?